# What does initial_epoch in Keras mean?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I'm a little bit confused about `initial_epoch` value in `fit` and `fit_generator` methods. Here is the [doc](https://keras.io/api/models/model_training_apis/):

> **initial_epoch**: Integer. Epoch at which to start training (useful for resuming a previous training run).

I understand, it is not useful if you start training from scratch. It is useful if you trained your dataset and want to improve accuracy or other values (*correct me if I'm wrong*). But I'm not sure what it really does.

So after all this, I have 2 questions:

1. What does `initial_epoch` do and what is it for?
2. When can I use `initial_epoch`?

- When I change my dataset?
- When I change the learning rate, optimizer or loss function?
- Both of them?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Since in some of the optimizers, some of their internal values (e.g. learning rate) are set using the **current** `epoch` value, or even you may have (custom) [callbacks](https://keras.io/callbacks/) that depend on the **current value** of `epoch`, the `initial_epoch` argument let you specify the initial value of `epoch` to start from when training.

As stated in the documentation, this is mostly useful when you have trained your model for some epochs, say 10, and then saved it and now you want to load it and resume the training for another 10 epochs **without disrupting the state of epoch-dependent objects (e.g. optimizer)**. So you would set `initial_epoch=10` (i.e. we have trained the model for 10 epochs) and `epochs=20` (not 10, since the total number of epochs to reach is 20) and then everything resume as if you were initially trained the model for 20 epochs in one single training session.

However, note that when using [built-in optimizers](https://keras.io/optimizers/) of Keras you don't need to use `initial_epoch`, since they store and update their state internally (without considering the value of current epoch) and also when saving a model the state of the optimizer will be stored as well.

Comment: Thanks for anwering @today. If I changed my dataset and not optimizer function or other programming flow, does it matter which initial_epoch I use?

Comment: @ibrahimözgön It depends on whether the dataset is similar (i.e. from the same distribution) to the previous dataset you have trained on. If it is similar, and you don't want to set `initial_epoch`, you could compile the model again and use a very low learning rate to start with, since already your model have learned something and starting with a very high learning rate may disrupt and entirely change the parameters it has learned so far; or alternatively, just set the `initial_epoch` to the number of epochs you have previously trained the model + 1.

Comment: Thank you again, i will try it.

Answer (score 6):

The answer above is correct however it is important to note that if you have trained for 10 epochs and set initial_epoch=10 and epochs=20 you train for 10 more epochs until you reach a total of 20 epochs. For example I trained for 2 epochs, then set initial_epoch=2 and epochs=4. The result is it trains for 4-2=2 more epochs. The new data in the history object starts at epoch 3. So the returned history object does start from epoch 1 as you might expect. Another words the state of the history object is not preserved from the initial training epochs. If you do not set initial_epoch and you train for 2 epochs, then rerun the fit_generator with epochs=4 it will train for 4 more epochs starting from the state preserved at the end of the second epoch (provided you use the built in optimizers). Again the history object state is NOT preserved from the initial training and only contains the data for the last 4 epochs. I noticed this because I plot the validation loss versus epochs.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example of how to integrate the initial_epoch in your code

```
#Training first 4 Epcohs and saving
model.fit(x_train, y_train, validation_data=(x_val, y_val), batch_size=32, epochs=4)
model.save("partial.h5")


#loading the model, training another 4 Epochs and then saving the updated model.
from keras.models import load_model
new_model = load_model('partial.h5')
new_model.fit(x_train, y_train, validation_data=(x_val, y_val), batch_size=32, initial_epoch=4,epochs=8)
new_model.save("updated.h5")
```

Also don't forget to specify a particular random_state value while splitting the data into train and test, so that it encounters the same set of training data each time you reinitiate the training process, so that there is no data leakage of test data entering the training data.