# Naming TensorFlow/Keras checkpoints

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am following the "Text generation with an RNN" tutorial on TensorFlow ([link](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/text/text_generation)). I have trained the model for 10 epochs, and would like to train it some more. I have already written the code that allows the model to resume training. (This resumes training starting from the most recent checkpoint -- in this case, checkpoint 10). It trains just fine. However, the saved checkpoints are overwriting the previous checkpoints. This is because when I rerun the code, the epoch number starts at 1 again. Therefore, when I have finished epochs 11 - 20, I still have only 10 checkpoints (1 - 10), but they have overwritten the previous 10 checkpoints. I would like to rename the new checkpoints to checkpoints 11 - 20, but have failed to do so. Here is the pertinent segment of the code:

```
# Directory where the checkpoints will be saved
checkpoint_dir = './training_checkpoints'
# Name of the checkpoint files
checkpoint_prefix = os.path.join(checkpoint_dir, "ckpt_{epoch+10}")

checkpoint_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(
    filepath=checkpoint_prefix,
    save_weights_only=True)

EPOCHS = 10
```

The only difference from the original code from the TensorFlow website is that I have modified the original line

```
checkpoint_prefix = os.path.join(checkpoint_dir, "ckpt_{epoch}")
```

to

```
checkpoint_prefix = os.path.join(checkpoint_dir, "ckpt_{epoch+10}")
```

However, it does not work. Here is the error:

```
KeyError: 'epoch+10'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "project/RNN_text_generator_finetune.py", line 102, in <module>
    history = model.fit(dataset, epochs=EPOCHS, callbacks=[checkpoint_callback])
  File "/opt/miniconda3/envs/newest11142020/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 108, in _method_wrapper
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/miniconda3/envs/newest11142020/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 1137, in fit
    callbacks.on_epoch_end(epoch, epoch_logs)
  File "/opt/miniconda3/envs/newest11142020/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/callbacks.py", line 412, in on_epoch_end
    callback.on_epoch_end(epoch, logs)
  File "/opt/miniconda3/envs/newest11142020/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/callbacks.py", line 1249, in on_epoch_end
    self._save_model(epoch=epoch, logs=logs)
  File "/opt/miniconda3/envs/newest11142020/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/callbacks.py", line 1282, in _save_model
    filepath = self._get_file_path(epoch, logs)
  File "/opt/miniconda3/envs/newest11142020/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/callbacks.py", line 1332, in _get_file_path
    raise KeyError('Failed to format this callback filepath: "{}". '
KeyError: 'Failed to format this callback filepath: "./training_checkpoints/ckpt_{epoch+10}". Reason: \'epoch+10\''
```

Is there any way to rename the checkpoints in the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set as follows when resuming training

```
model.fit(..., 
     initial_epoch=epoch,
     ..)
```

Here, `initial_epoch` is an integer. Epoch at which to start training, it's useful for resuming a previous training run). Let's say you've trained a model at epoch `10` and stop training. So, when resuming the training, set the `initial_epoch` at `10`. [Src](https://keras.io/api/models/model_training_apis/), and insightfull [discussin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52476191/what-does-initial-epoch-in-keras-mean).